# Visual Studio 2010 Add-in OnBuild event callback

Tags: c#, visual-studio, add-in, vs-extensibility

I have a VS 2010 add-in and I am looking to expose a callback to be fired when the user builds a project. Any ideas?

Comment: u mean you are writing this add-in ?

Comment: Yes. I already have the add-in partially written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check this: [BuildEventsClass.OnBuildBegin Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.buildeventsclass.onbuildbegin.aspx)

Comment: Thanks - this worked. I would direct anyone else attempting to do this to the following website: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsx/thread/ee827d4f-db11-497b-9135-bb344a144d52